# Create PostgreSQL partitions automatically

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I need help to understand if partitions for PostgreSQL table can be created automatically using triggers.

For e.g., to create daily partition based on range partition and then sub-partitions of that based on hash partition, I am creating this script manually as below:

```
CREATE TABLE source_record_0518 PARTITION OF source_record
FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-05-18T00:00:00') TO ('2023-05-19T00:00:00')
Partition by hash(source_record_uuid);

CREATE TABLE source_record_0518_sub_1 PARTITION OF source_record_0518
FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 8, REMAINDER 0)

CREATE TABLE source_record_0518_sub_2 PARTITION OF source_record_0518
FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 8, REMAINDER 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot create partitions with triggers, at least not with triggers fired from the statements that insert data into the table. You will have to use a job scheduler of your choice to create the partitions. With a daily partitioning scheme, that should be simple.

There are tools that provide automatic partition creation, the best is perhaps pg_partman.